# Springframework.data.domain.page.map SpelEvaluationException "Property of field "timestamp" cannot be found.."

Tags: java, spring, pagination, spring-data, spelevaluationexception

I try to implement pagination support. After successfully getting a Page from the service I want to convert it to objects which have the given Strings as primary keys. After the paging information should remain.

I tried the following:

```
Page<String> userIds = studentService.getAllUserIds(pageable);
Page<StudentStatistics> studentStatistics = userIds.map(new Converter<String, StudentStatistics>(){
            @Override
            public StudentStatistics convert(String userId) {
                return answerService.getUserStatistics(userId);
            }
        });
```

Or:

```
List<StudentStatistics> studentStatistics = new ArrayList<StudentStatistics>();
    for(String userId : userIds){
        studentStatistics.add(answerService.getUserStatistics(userId));
    }
new PageImpl<>(studentStatistics, pageable, userIds.getTotalElements()));
```

Both ended up in the exception:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'timestamp' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.HashMap' - maybe not public?
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:224)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:94)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$ExpressionResolver.resolvePlaceholder(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:279)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper$NonRecursivePlaceholderResolver.resolvePlaceholder(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:56)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(NonRecursivePropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:38)
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView.render(ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.java:217)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1037)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:980)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) 
...
```

Why does this exception get thrown in this case? Does the Page entity has timestamp properties?

What would be an elegant way to solve this?

Kind regards

---

UPDATE: The spel.SpelEvaluationException error is usually caused when you have an error in the query syntax of the repository module. When you do not use native queries you can face this error using the Spel feature of Springs queries.

Comment: Why do you think the code you showed relates to the exception? (it probably doesn't)

Comment: If I comment out the conversion lines and return the Page of userIds directly it works just fine, thus I thought it must be related in some way..

Comment: so by creating a local variable, that goes nowhere, you create a stacktrace that has no connection to the code you introduced? Strange.

Comment: I mean there must be a connection. I will post updates when investigating more.

Comment: Oh, I think I skipped a line. You are returning the result. So show us the `StudentStatistics` class.

Comment: Also, where is this code? A webMVC Controller or Something?

Comment: The error was caused from my query annotation when getting student statistics. I had to correctly reference a.userId instead of only userId. Sorry for pointing out the wrong error source and thank you for trying to help Jens!